# Power BI Dynamic Table Title based on individual account rank

Tags: powerbi, dax, rank, dynamic-tables

I have created a series of monthly sales tables in Power BI using a DAX formula to rank an account as number 1 or number 20 based on total sales.  Account name in my database is "National Account Franchise Name".  While there is probably a better way to set up bringing in the information for each table, I have the table working correctly.  However, the name of that account that is number 1 or number whatever wont show up on the table.  The ranked account will change based on filters that I choose, so the account needs to be dynamic. What is the correct DAX code to write and put into the title?

DAX Code using to get my table to work:
[DAX Coding for finding top client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUhUD.png)

What my table looks like.  Blue Area is where the number 1 ranked account name should be, but currently has random numbers.
[Sales Table by month for Top Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNHjE.png)

Tried to write a couple dax codes and then add it as conditional formatting in the title.  But can't seem to figure out the correct DAX coding that simply gets me the account name.